# Query does not produce a result set when trying to delete by date.

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a method in java that will delete all records in a database before a certain date. Right now I'm getting this SQLException: Query or procedure does not return a result set.

This is one of the insert statements that my unit test uses to populate the db.

```
INSERT INTO C35_6 ( xIndex, xcSource, dTimeOn, dTimeOff, bSuccessful ) 
VALUES (74013, 1, '05/01/1972 00:00:00.000', '05/02/1972 00:00:00.000', 1 )
```

And here's the delete statement

```
DELETE FROM C35_6 WHERE dTimeOff <= '12/31/1975 00:00:00.000'
```

I can see in the log file that these statements are running in the correct order, right after one another. These statements are being created with java preparedStatement using setDate().

It seems like sql for some reason can't compare these dates.

Comment: are you using executeQuery instead of execute?

Comment: Yes this was the problem.

Comment: The problem is in the Java code, not in the SQL statement. Show the Java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the fact you're setting a date is irrelevant. The exception message says that the "query does not return a result set". This is true. Both of your queries do not return results.

The implication is that you're executing them in the wrong way. My guess is that you running them with `preparedStatement.executeQuery()` (which is for `SELECT` queries and expects to return a `ResultSet`) rather than [`preparedStatement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()) which can be used on any type of query.

Comment: Yes this did the trick thanks. You're right about the red herring, I was fixated on comparing the dates and didn't even think that the execution was the problem.

Comment: No problem. I can understand why you made that assumption. Dates are notoriously tricky. But Java error messages are pretty decent on the whole - at least for telling you what the problem is, not necessarily telling you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Elevate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162163/642706) is correct as to the cause of your exception being unrelated to date-time handling.

But you *do* have problems with your date-time handling.

- Ignoring crucial issue of time zone.
- Using dumb strings instead of smart objects.

Here is a full example use the [H2 Database](http://h2database.com/).

A `ZonedDateTime` object represents a moment, a point on the timeline, as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)).

We can view that same moment, that same point on the timeline, through the wall-clock time of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) simply by extracting a `Instant` from our [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The JDBC driver for H2 Database requires an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), as its `PreparedStatement::setObject` method seems unable to deal with a `ZonedDateTime` directly. Most databases, including H2, store a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in UTC. Some will adjust incoming values from another time zone to UTC, but apparently H2 requires us to do the adjustment.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.*;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt () {
        JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:bogus;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );  // Create in-memory database that disappears when this JVM exits.
        ds.setUser( "sa" );  // Arbitrary.
        ds.setPassword( "sa" );

        ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); // Arbitrarily chosen time zone.

        // Define "event" table with 3 columns: id number auto-generated, beginning of event, ending of event.
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_  ( id_ INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , start_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, stop_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL ) ;";
        try (
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            stmt.executeUpdate( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert rows for years 1972, 1977, & 1973.
        sql = "INSERT INTO event_ (  start_ , stop_ ) VALUES ( ? , ? ) ; ";
        try (
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        ) {
            ps.setObject( 1 , LocalDate.of( 1972 , Month.MAY , 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant() );
            ps.setObject( 2 , LocalDate.of( 1972 , Month.MAY , 2 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant() );
            ps.executeUpdate();

            ps.setObject( 1 , LocalDate.of( 1977 , Month.JUNE , 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant() );
            ps.setObject( 2 , LocalDate.of( 1977 , Month.JULY , 2 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant() );
            ps.executeUpdate();

            ps.setObject( 1 , LocalDate.of( 1973 , Month.AUGUST , 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant() );
            ps.setObject( 2 , LocalDate.of( 1973 , Month.AUGUST , 2 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant() );
            ps.executeUpdate();


        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Dump table.
        System.out.println( "Dumping event_ table. " );
        sql = "SELECT * FROM event_  ; ";
        try (
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
        ) {
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                System.out.println( "id_:  " + rs.getInt( 1 ) + " | " + rs.getObject( 2 , Instant.class ).atZone( z ) + " to " + rs.getObject( 3 , Instant.class ).atZone( z ) );
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Deleting rows for events starting before beginning of 1976. Should delete 2 of our 3 rows, leaving 1 row.
        System.out.println( "Deleting rows. " );
        sql = "DELETE FROM event_ WHERE start_ < ? ; ";
        try (
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        ) {
            ps.setObject( 1 , Year.of( 1976 ).atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant() );  // First moment of 1976 in our time zone.
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Dump table.
        System.out.println( "Dumping event_ table. " );
        sql = "SELECT * FROM event_  ; ";
        try (
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
        ) {
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                System.out.println( "id_:  " + rs.getInt( 1 ) + " | " + rs.getObject( 2 , Instant.class ).atZone( z ) + " to " + rs.getObject( 3 , Instant.class ).atZone( z ) );
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

When run.

> Dumping event_ table.
>
> id_:  1 | 1972-05-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal] to 1972-05-02T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> id_:  2 | 1977-06-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal] to 1977-07-02T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> id_:  3 | 1973-08-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal] to 1973-08-02T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> Deleting rows.
>
> Dumping event_ table.
>
> id_:  2 | 1977-06-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal] to 1977-07-02T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).